# How to use helpers function inside route file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to encrypt url in codeigniter, i have created a function encode_url() in helper and decode_url() for decode using codeigniter encrypt library , i add link as encode_url("home") and want to route this url to home controller but i can not access helper function in route file.
Is there is any way to route url using decode function or i will have to create new function in controller and decode there.
Encode function in helper

```
function encode_url($string, $key="", $url_safe=TRUE)
{

if($key==null || $key=="")
{
    $key="sh_hebrewurlencryption";
}
  $CI =& get_instance();
$ret = $CI->encrypt->encode($string, $key);

if ($url_safe)
{
    $ret = strtr(
            $ret,
            array(
                '+' => '.',
                '=' => '-',
                '/' => '~'
            )
        );
}

return $ret;
}
```

**Decode function in helper**

```
function encode_url($string, $key="", $url_safe=TRUE)
{

if($key==null || $key=="")
{
    $key="sh_hebrewurlencryption";
}
  $CI =& get_instance();
$ret = $CI->encrypt->encode($string, $key);

if ($url_safe)
{
    $ret = strtr(
            $ret,
            array(
                '+' => '.',
                '=' => '-',
                '/' => '~'
            )
        );
}

return $ret;
}
```

And url in menu like

```
<?php echo site_url();?>he/<?php echo encode_url('checkMemberStatus'); ?>
```

Comment: Seems you posted same functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the helper first in your function then you can use it

```
$this->load->library('encryption');
```

Reference can be [found here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html) on official codeigniter